# how to get the content of tr having only a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have a table created dynamically some tr have class subfunction .i want get the content of tr having class subfunction iuse

```
var k = $(("#table tr").hasClass("subfunction")).text()
```

i want the all tr content having subfunction class for example i need `k = [hai,jai,vinu,]` somthing like this

Comment: `$("#table tr.subfunction").text()` ... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tr.subfunction` you can filter out `tr` with the class. To get as an array use **[`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)** method.

```
var k = $("#table tr.subfunction").map(function(){
  return $(this).text(); 
}).get();
```

---

For getting combined text use **[`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** method.

```
var k = $("#table tr.subfunction").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="subfunction">
            <td>abcd</td>
            <td>xyz</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="subfunction">
            <td>xyz</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>34</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $($('#table').find('.subfunction')).each(function(){
        $(this).text();
    });
});
</script>
```

Fiddle[Check](https://jsfiddle.net/eradi_singh/rqcd15kn/)